# python pandas reattach column after aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, merge, aggregate

My DataFrame looks like this

```
exams = pd.DataFrame({'id1':['1x', '1x','2x','3x','3x'], 'id2':['a','a','b','a','a'],'data':[1,2,3,4,5]}) 

    id1    id2   data
0    1x      a      1
1    1x      a      2
2    2x      b      3
3    3x      a      4
4    3x      a      5
```

Then I aggregate it to

```
exams_agg = exams.groupby('id1').agg('mean')
```

Then `exams_agg` looks like

```
       data
id1
 1x      1.5
 2x        3
 3x      4.5
```

I want to reattach `id2` column to `exams_agg`. So I was thinking about create a lookup table

```
lookup = exams[['id1', 'id2']]
exams_agg = pd.merge(exams_agg, lookup, left_index=True, right_on='id1')
```

But since `lookup` contains duplicate pairs of ids, `exams_agg` contains duplicates as well. What is a good way to create

```
       data    id2
id1
 1x      1.5     a
 2x        3     b
 3x      4.5     a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a unique `id1` always corresponds to the same `id2`, you can simply add `id2` in your `groupby` :

```
In [5]: df.groupby(['id1', 'id2']).agg('mean')
Out[5]: 
         data
id1 id2      
1x  a     1.5
2x  b     3.0
3x  a     4.5
```

Comment: They are. Thank you so much. I should have thought about it.